# After converting hashcode into String I can't reconvert it to int in Java

Tags: java

I have a problem with the method that aims to print a hypothetical new hashCode for my class. I am trying to create for each object a hashcode that will be composed of the hashCodes of two String variables of my class. That's my code:

```
public void printHashCodes(){
    String plateNumber = String.valueOf(this.liNumber.hashCode()) + String.valueOf(this.country.hashCode());
    int hashCodeToConvert = Integer.valueOf(plateNumber);
    System.out.println(hashCodeToConvert);
    System.out.println(plateNumber);
}
```

Whenever I delete "hashCodeToConvert" lines and print a String called "plateNumber" method works fine. From that I understand that conversion of joined hashCodes to String was succesful.

Whenever I replace the content of the "plateNumber" String with some constant value like "123456789" the method works fine too so the code must be working well but in the form above it just doesn't work.

I assume there must be some limitation in conversion of potentially unlimited String into limited primitive int but what is the actual reason and what is the solution for that problem?

Clarification: My actual aim is to make a hashCode for an object but I am using printHashCodes method to verify those hashCodes. Since hashCode must be an int I have to reconvert it into int. It cannot stay as String(**as farest I know**)

Comment: Why are you trying to convert it to int in the first place if you just want to print it out?

Comment: if you want to just print a "hypothetical new hashCode" whatever that might mean, why do you need to convert it to int?

Comment: My actual aim is to make a hashCode for object but I am using printHashCodes method to verify them. Since hashCode must be an int I have to reconvert it into int

Comment: So why do you convert the returned hashcode, which is already an int, first to String and then back to int again?

Comment: How can I join two numbers(not adding them but joining) without prior conversion to String? 5 + 5 = 10 but I want it to be 55

Comment: I assume the problematic line in your code is `int hashCodeToConvert = Integer.valueOf(plateNumber);` Have you tried first printing out plateNumber, before the problem occurs? Woud that output make sense to be converted to int? Maybe it exceeds the value range for int? or what exact error do you perceive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see two reasons why your code is failing.
First, the result of `String.valueOf(this.liNumber.hashCode()) + String.valueOf(this.country.hashCode())` could be too big.

The maximum value for an integer is 2147483647.

Secondly, the output of the `hashCode()` method could be below zero, and the value of `plateNumber`could be `2147483647-1164645587`, which is not easy to transform into an integer.

In both cases, it will throw a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

For me, the easiest solution would be to create a hashcode for an object that would contain these two values.
Or to use this:

```
return Objects.hash(liNumber, country);
```

Comment: What could be a solution for that? I want to create an unique hashCode for an object based on its content and not reference. I want two objects with the same variables to have the same hashCode. But nevertheless different than objects with different variables.

Comment: If you use an IDE (either Eclipse or IntelliJ at least can do this) just let it generate the hashCode method, it will create a proper implementation for it.

Comment: But keep in mind, that the hashCode method itself is not guaranteed to always return distinct values, when you compare two objects (that's simply not possible with an int as data type), that's what the equals method is for.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to avoid automatic generation to learn more about the hashCodes but it might be above mu current level. I am aware that uniqueness is limited just as int variable is limited